Nextjs 14 randomly throwing 404 not found on reloading scripts and stylesheets on local environment
Encountered an issue where all the scripts and stylesheet requests are failing on page reload. Causing the app to become unusable.
Tried rebuilding the app, checking for path alias issues. Most help online relates to the next router issues such as with , none of these seems to work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Anyone encountering this, the solution is to delete the complete .next folder from the root directory. This will rebuild the whole thing from scratch and seems to fix the issue.
